# How to add a custom header in every JSS layout service request in Node JS reverse proxy solution template

Tags: jss, layout-service

We are using Sitecore 10.2/Headless/JSS React, also we enabled server-side rendering by hosting behind the [Headless JSS proxy](https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/hd/200/sitecore-headless-development/walkthrough--rendering-a-jss-app-server-side-using-the-headless-jss-proxy.html).

We require every layout service to authenticate in the backend(Sitecore), and we need to set a `custom authorize header` for every layout service call. Especially we need this on the server side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is doable in Node JS reverse proxy template.

1. Go to \src\config.ts
2. Under the `ProxyConfig => proxyOptions`. Basically, this is `http-proxy-middleware`, so you can customize it like here.
3. Add the example of the below line,

```
   /*
   * Add custom headers for the layout service here
   */
    onProxyReq: function (proxyReq: any) {
        proxyReq.setHeader('Authorization', "Value here");          
    }
```